# Differentiate between Broadcast Receivers with same actions

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

Here is the situation:

***What to DO:***
I have two Broadcast receivers for GCM Messages, and both of them have the same permissions and are listening for REGISTRATION and RECEIVE actions.
Now one of the Broadcast receiver is listening to my own Server and another Broadcast Receiver is supposed to be listening to gcm messages from a third party server.

***The Problem***
Since both of them are listening to gcm messages, whenever a push notification comes in , both the receivers are invoked. How to configure the receivers so that one of them only listens to my Server and another one only listens to a third party server

Comment: "Now one of the Broadcast receiver is listening to my own Server and another Broadcast Receiver is supposed to be listening to gcm messages from a third party server" -- why? Why not have *one* `BroadcastReceiver` that inspects the message, then delegates the work to whatever is supposed to handle it?

Comment: Yes that's one good way to do it, but security requirements prevent be from doing that, and dictate a this isn't an option unforutnately Else I would have created a class and delegated receivers from there . But thank you for your reply.!

Comment: Yes as @CommonsWare suggested that might be the only way . Any thoughts about setting priority to broadcast receivers ? Setting high to one and low to another, can that be manipulated to acheive this goal ?

Comment: Also @CommonsWare what are the disadvantages of having two BroadcastReceiver for the same actions? Because as per GoogleAnalytics  "Only one broadcast receiver can be specified per application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to configure the receivers so that one of them only listens to my Server and another one only listens to a third party server

This is not possible. You cannot set up an `<intent-filter>` based on GCM message content or originator. Your choices are:

1. Have both `BroadcastReceivers` be invoked for all GCM messages for your app.
2. Have only one `BroadcastReceiver`, per my comment.
3. Eliminate one source of the messages.
4. Migrate one source of the messages to something other than GCM.
5. Raise 390.76 billion USD, acquire Google, and force them to engineer a solution for allowing different `BroadcastReceiver` `<intent-filter>` elements based upon message content or originator. Note that the actual dollar figure may vary depending upon market conditions and does not include brokerage or legal fees. Please consult with your financial advisor before investing.

Comment: 1. Has anything changed since this answer was written? 2. Is there an authoritative documentation link about this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: @AdamMatan: "Has anything changed since this answer was written?" -- there's a new [topic feature added in GCM 3.0](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging), but that wouldn't seem to be able to solve the OP's concern. Otherwise, no. "Is there an authoritative documentation link about this issue?" -- I doubt it, as there are an infinite number of unsupported things ("is there documentation about having GCM messages be received by a bowl of macaroni and cheese?").

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. 1. You might be interested [with this bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584881/android-sdk-gets-notregistered-error-from-gcm-after-a-few-hours). 2. When you name your versions after candies, yeah, some mac and cheese would be well received!

Answer (score 0):

Can you send a custom "Action" in each of the pushes? Then you can filter based on the action.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyCustomReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".MyCustomReceiver2" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION2" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: GCM is the one controlling the action strings, as the Play Services engine is the one sending the broadcasts.

Comment: Ah, well in that case your solution of a single `BroadcastReceiver` is the best option.