# Android SDK gets NotRegistered error from GCM after a few hours

Tags: android, sdk, google-cloud-messaging

## The problem

I am writing and Android SDK which should receive GCM push messages from the SDK server side. After a few hours of successful push message sending, the GCM server returns an `NotRegistered` error:

```
{
    "multicast_id":6205350692941230304,
    "success":0,
    "failure":1,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":
    [
        {
            "error":"NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `registrationId` at the client has not changed, and the server side is updated with that token.

**How can I fix the `registrationId` problem? Is having two listeners - one in the SDK, one in the app - a problem?**

## Architecture

My Android SDK registers a GCM `regId` upon initialization, and sends that id to the server supporting the SDK.

The embracing app might (and usually do) register a GCM `regId` of its own. The other `regId` is probably sent to the embracing app's server.

The `senderId` of the SDK and app are different.

## Implementation

### Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> ...

    <receiver
        android:name="com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

### Registration code

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String msg = "";
    try {
        if (gcm == null) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
        }
        regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
        storeRegistrationId(mContext, regid);
        listener.onGCMRegisterFinish(regid);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return msg;
}
```

This code gets the `regId` from the GCM Server and send it to our backend server. It is executed at the SDK initialization, and the `regId` is sent every time the app returns from background.

#### Notes

- `unregister()` is not called, neither from server or client side
- I am raising a toast with the registration id every once in a while, so I can verify it is the same between the client and the server:

Client side

[image]

Server side

```
2015-08-02 12:31:22,383 INFO - request_2145354041215926507 
                        update push token for user: XXXXXXXX,
                        push_token: ...me1GttmSRipnWsCGVUueK7e0nk
```

Answer (score 5):

Add Category with your package name to the `intent-filter`

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".xxxxx"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.xxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate why this should work, and add some documentation links? I want this to be an authoritative, canonical answer.

Answer (score 2):

The registration ID´s generation includes not only the device but also the app and the sender ID. If I understood your architecture correctly you want to implement a GCM-client-library (your SDK) enabling your app to use GCM through your library? If that´s true make sure that you only register once

> The senderId of the SDK and app are different

I assume this is the problem, you have to register each app with a sender id (e.g. XYZ) and use the SAME sender id at the server to send the notification. It is not possible to use ABC as sender id to send notifications to a device registered for sender id XYZ

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide supporting links to your claim?

Comment: I am afraid not, sorry. The reason is that you are using the deprecated API version, Google removed the old official docs, nevertheless I know that you have to use an equal sender id for sending and receiving because I also develop GCM apps (anything else would not make sense anyway because this is for security in order to guarantee that the server is authorized to send notifications to the device) Here you have the link to the new InstanceID-API https://developers.google.com/instance-id/ I can highly recommend to use both, the new InstanceId as well as the new GCM Api