# Android Manifest Intent-filter category: SDK name or app name?

Tags: android, sdk, google-cloud-messaging, intentfilter

My team is building an [Android SDK which should receive GCM push messages independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584881/android-sdk-gets-notregistered-error-from-gcm-after-a-few-hours), regardless of pushes sent to the enclosing app.

After some trouble getting pushes, [we were advised to add `<category android:name="com.xxxx" />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774268/51197) to the `intent-filter` if the Manifest.

```
<receiver
      android:name=".xxxxx"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.xxxx" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**What should be the value of `category android`? The SDK package, or the app package?**

Comment: category is your app package.  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: As the link only contains an example but no explicit explanation I am sure that this should be seen as the final proof...

Comment: Of course I meant "I am NOT sure that this should be seen as the final proof"...